# js code doesn't work on web hosting but it works on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to run some AJAX code on my web hosting. The problem is that it works on my localhost but it doesn't work on my web hosting. Do anybody know how to solve this problem?

This is the code:

```
function validarCorreo(mail){
  var bool = false;
  var mail = {"mail" : mail};
  $.ajax({
    data: mail,
    url: '/carepets/validaciones/validarCorreo.php',
     type: 'post',
    async: false,
     success: function(response){
       if(response == true){
        $("#autenticacionCorreo").html("El correo esta      disponible.").css("color","green");
        bool = true;
      }else{
        $("#autenticacionCorreo").html("El correo esta ya registrado o es incorrecto.").css("color","red");
      }
    }
  });
  return bool;
}
```

Comment: Take a look in the browser's console to see if there are any errors. This is probably a CORS problem.

Comment: What is the error you get in the console?

Comment: nsLoginManager: searchLogins: `formSubmitURL` or `httpRealm` is recommended

Comment: Is Ajax called ?

Comment: @bakero98 yes Ajax is called. It works properly on my localhost but not on mi web hosting

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you should check:
Check if you properly included jQuery in your project. 
Also check if relative path of validarCorreo.php file is correct on your server and if it is ok then check if there are no errors in that file. 
It would be good if you could check your Network Activity tab to see and share with us what happens when you invoke validarCorreo function.